# getting "primary": $primary-text-emphasis-dark error while converting scss to css

Tags: css, sass

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU177.png)

```
@import "Documents/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha2/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "Documents/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha2/scss/_variables.scss";

@each $color , $value in $grays {
    .bg-#{$color} {
        background-color: $value;
    }
}

@import "Documents/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha2/scss/_maps.scss";
@import "Documents/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha2/scss/_mixins.scss";
@import "Documents/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha2/scss/_root.scss";
```

I tried reordering functions and variables but it does not work .

Comment: Are you using webpack 5.77.0?

Comment: It's a breaking change in a minor Bootstrap version (5.2 - 5.3) [that was fixed but not yet released](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/39380). You can either import variables-dark or just downgrade to 5.2.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`@import "_variables-dark.scss"`  before `@import "_map.scss"` will work.

The `primary-text-emphasis-dark` variable is defined in `_variables-dark.scss`

Comment: I believe there's a dependency on variables-dark when you're adding your own maps, such as custom colors. I'm not sure if this is intended behaviour or just an alpha bug.

Comment: @NickPearce, it is not a bug. If not used, dark mode should be disabled via `$enable-dark-mode` variable. Detailed answer below.

Comment: I just added it before _maps.scss and it worked perfect for me.. thanks

Answer (score 10):

You should disable specific `_variable-XXX.scss` file for your given color modes, if you are not planning on using them.

Since Bootstrap 5.3 comes with dark-mode enabled (via `$enable-dark-mode` variable), it assumes `_variables-dark.scss` file to be imported before `_maps.scss` is.

Just add `$enable-dark-mode: false` after importing `_variables.scss`, but before importing `_maps.scss` and you are good to go.