# SassError: Undefined variable."primary": $primary-text-emphasis-dark in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

While building my react app i got error as shown in picture and using  "sass": "1.32.1" and bootstrap version 5.0.2. There is no any error while "npm start" but while building(npm run build in Jenkins), error occur.

[image: Error Schreenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting "primary": $primary-text-emphasis-dark error while converting scss to css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75873195/getting-primary-primary-text-emphasis-dark-error-while-converting-scss-to-cs)

Answer (score 9):

Bootstrap 5.3.0 (latest at the moment) added support for dark and light modes.

I have solved the same problem (although unrelated to ReactJS) by adding new bootstrap source file `variables-dark.scss`, after already existing `variables.scss` in my main `site.scss` file:

```scss
// site.scss
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";
```

More details can be found in Bootstrap Sass documentation for version 5.3 [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/#importing).

Other, perhaps easier option, if your ReactJS framework does not support Bootstrap 5.3 yet is to lock version of Bootstrap in `package.json` file to `5.2.x` for now:

```json
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "bootstrap": "~5.2.0"
  ...
},
```

Comment: using bootstrap 5.0.2 but not working

Comment: Double check if you updated Bootstrap by accident. `variables-dark` did not exist until 5.3.0 (which was released yesterday or day before). Also, just noticed my error for `package.json`. Dependency has to have `~` in front, not `^`. So `"bootstrap": "~5.2.0". Your package manager has downloaded latest version of Bootstrap.

Comment: adding the `-dark` version worked for us. Curiously, this issue was only happening for one of the developers on our team

Comment: Following up on the above... while adding -dark did work for one developer whose npm was getting Bootstrap 5.3, adding `-dark` broke in our build environment because its npm was still getting 5.2.3. So we wound up pinning Bootstrap at 5.2.3

Comment: @LeifJones When there is `package-lock.json` (or `yarn.lock`) in the project, running `npm install` would not automatically try to update `^5.2.3` to `5.3.0`. Probably some developers had it auto-generated in the project and others did not. It is recommended to commit `package-lock.json` into a git repository, so that build server restores exact versions of packages upon `npm install` command.

Comment: Hmm, there was package-lock.json in the project (and committed to the repo). Perhaps it was temporarily locally deleted (because sometimes we delete it and node_modules when there's an issue after an Angular version update).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify Bootstrap version as 5.2.x, not above. Bootstrap 5.3 requires the import of scss/variables-dark

Comment: Pinning the Bootstrap version(5.2.0) works for me.